# Apply the same transformation on separated arrays (without concatenating)

Tags: python, pca

I have 2-D data of shape `(?, n)` where `?` may differ from one sample to another. Each sample corresponds to one recording, each recording is of time-length `?` and `n` is the number of features (same for all recordings).

I want to apply an operation, that is independent component analysis, on all of samples. ICA is kind of PCA and will reduce my number of features to, let's say `m < n`. However, of course, this operation has to be done on the overall dataset. But, I don't want to concatenate all my recordings because I need to keep "distinguishing" them. How can I proceed ?

Thanks for help !